# unable to setText of button in customized navigational drawer

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have made a **customised navigational drawer** with 3 buttons and I want to change text on the buttons according to the activity they are associated with. So when I made a java object of the layout of navigational drawer using LayoutInflater and got handle of each button using findViewById on that layout object, I set Text of each button but when i am running the app the **text does not appear**(in XML I have not set any text for the buttons). Rest all is working fine.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sahil.childcare.NavigationalDrawerFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <include
          layout="@layout/nav_profile"
          android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/nav_profile"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
          android:id="@+id/top_button"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/top_button"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
          android:id="@+id/middle_button" />
    <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/middle_button"
          android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The **part of the code** in main activity(***inside onCreate() method***) involving this drawer is here

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigational_drawer,null);
    Button topButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.top_button);
    Button middleButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.middle_button);
    Button bottomButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_button);
    topButton.setText("School");
    topButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    middleButton.setText("Teacher");
    middleButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    bottomButton.setText("Child");
    bottomButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd check if the buttons are even visible on screen.
To do that you can set them some color background, e.g.:

```
android:background="#ff0000"
```

and also use [hierarchy-viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) to make sure your buttons appear where you expect them to appear.

Next thing to check is if the newly inflated `fragment_navigational_drawer` is actually being used for the Navigation Drawer, or maybe it's a different instance of this layout, to do that you can add some logging to the inflation code, printing the specific instance you put on screen, and verifying in hierarchy-viewer you see the right instance on screen.

**UPDATE:**

For completeness of the answer, per comments below, if you already added a layout via xml (e.g. using `<include>`), instead of inflating it in code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigational_drawer,null);
```

you need to get a handle of the already inflated layout, via something like:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.my_navigational_drawer);
```

Comment: thank you for the efforts. When i set text using XML its appears. I think its a different instance because when I set 'onClickListener' to the button to go to the respective activities, it does not happen (even the Log shows this as i kept few logs inside 'onClickListener()').But how could it inflate different instance.please tell this as well.

Comment: post the code that makes use of the inflated `view`

Comment: you were right there were two instances of the drawer. I created one by inflating the drawer fragment and one by adding the fragment inside the xml layout. The changes I made were belonging to the inflated drawer and not the actual drawer appearing in my app. Thank you for the help marmor.